# Removing a string from a slice in Go

Tags: string, go, slice

I have a slice of strings, and I want to remove a specific one.

```
strings := []string
strings = append(strings, "one")
strings = append(strings, "two")
strings = append(strings, "three")
```

Now how can I remove the string `"two"` from `strings`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025409/delete-element-in-a-slice

Answer (score 26):

Find the element you want to remove and remove it like you would any element from any other slice.

Finding it is a linear search. Removing is one of the following [slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks):

```
a = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
// or
a = a[:i+copy(a[i:], a[i+1:])]
```

Here is the complete solution (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/9vyR6W-41m)):

```
s := []string{"one", "two", "three"}

// Find and remove "two"
for i, v := range s {
    if v == "two" {
        s = append(s[:i], s[i+1:]...)
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println(s) // Prints [one three]
```

If you want to wrap it into a function:

```
func remove(s []string, r string) []string {
    for i, v := range s {
        if v == r {
            return append(s[:i], s[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

Using it:

```
s := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
s = remove(s, "two")
fmt.Println(s) // Prints [one three]
```

Comment: Fails in cases with multiple occurrence such as `s := []string{"one", "two", "two", "three"}`

Comment: @Stanislav That's right, because intention was not to remove all occurrences, but to remove _a_ string from a slice (as the question title says).

Comment: In defence of @Stanislav I get where he is coming from. I have no idea why `append` is a built-in but `remove` is not. Especially, when dealing with slices of strings, these are standard functions that practically every language in broad use other than C comes with out of the box. How many times has this sort of function had to be implemented when it could have been included in the standard library? We have a `strings` library for operating on string types as a slice of runes. This is part of the problem with an interface definition only being fulfilled on structs...

Comment: Before removal, I have 2 elements `[602139dfb72f0dec8cf66da6 602139dfb72f0dec8cf66da7]` and after removal I get `[          602139dfb72f0dec8cf66da6]`. You can see that I am getting a space. Do I need to trim this ? and how?

Comment: @MuhammadTariq No, you do not. I don't see your code so I can't help you. It works for me.

Comment: @icza, Here is the code `for k, value := range mySlice{
  if value == questionID {
    myslice = append(mySlice[:k], mySlice[k+1:]...)
    break
    } 
}` When I print `mySlice`, I get the space as defined in above comment.

Comment: You can't `range` over a slice and modify it at the same time. See [How to remove element of struct array in loop in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005825/how-to-remove-element-of-struct-array-in-loop-in-golang/29006008#29006008)

Comment: Thanks @icza. Actually the problem was my slice declaration `var mySlice = make([]string,10)`. After some hit and try, I changed the capacity to ZERO `var mySlice = make([]string,0)` and it solved the problem. I checked with `range` and it gave me the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to remove the element at a particular index:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "errors"

func main() {
    strings := []string{}
    strings = append(strings, "one")
    strings = append(strings, "two")
    strings = append(strings, "three")
    strings, err := remove(strings, 1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Something went wrong : ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(strings)
    }

}

func remove(s []string, index int) ([]string, error) {
    if index >= len(s) {
        return nil, errors.New("Out of Range Error")
    }
    return append(s[:index], s[index+1:]...), nil
}
```

Try it on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6dBqnzx3SI)

Comment: Users may want to be aware that this will affect the original slice. If you run the 'remove' function and then try to access the original slice, it won't look the same. See https://play.golang.org/p/Sa2xYyk6atI